# Euclidean Ball Formula Derivation

Tags: optimization, vectors

This is from Boyd's Optimization textbook (2.2.2). I am confused as to how to derive the RHS from the LHS of the Euclidean ball equation, centered at $x_c$, with radius $r$, and $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$: $$B(x_c, r) = \{x \space | \space \|x-x_c \|_2 \leq r\} = \{x_c + ru \space| \space \|u\|_2 \leq 1\}$$.

Edit: We can do a change of variables on the RHS.

Here is my approach: 
pick new variable $u$ such that $x - x_c = u$. Now replace the first expression --> $\{ x_c + u \space | \space \|u\|_2 \leq r \}$, then we can replace r with 1 and scale $u$ so that we get $\{ x_c + ru \space | \space \|u\|_2 \leq 1 \}$.

Is my reasoning correct here?

Comment: Hint . What vectors Boyd describes in both those formulations ? What are the vectors $ru$ when $r$ is arbitrary and $u$ has a maximum length of one ?

Comment: This reasoning is correct.

Comment: Thank you for your help!